# Changing direction in 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation

I am working on a 3D project, in Unity.

I have an object moving in a confined space. The object have a fixed velocity, and it bounces back once they reach the space limit.

I want it to change direction once every n seconds.

The problem I am facing is: How to rotate a 3D vector by a given angle.

In 2D is pretty easy, while in 3D I am not sure how to handle it.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You rotate things using quaternions, however they are a rather broad topic. You need to specify what you mean by "a change of direction" and "a given angle"

Comment: I have a 2D project in which there are moving objects, that once every n seconds change direction of a given angle belonging to [-alpha, +alpha]. In 2D this situation is pretty simple.
Well, I need to implement a similar movement logic in 3D. The fact is that in 3D I don't really know how to apply a directional change, having the angle of this change. I suppose it should be on the cone such that the vertex of the cone is my object, and the angle between the height of the cone and one vector tangent to it and passing through the vertex is equal to my angle, however I do not know how to do it

Comment: are you looking to rotate on a specific axis (not necessary a cardinal) or a completely random one?

Comment: How did you rotate in 2D? Can you show some code? In Unity the rotation is controlled by the Transform class, so it should be the same between 2D and 3D.

Comment: how are you setting velocity? do you have `Rigidbody` on the moving object?

Comment: if you want to rotate the gameObject you would not need to rotate a vector but the gameObject itself. You can consider setting `transform.localRotation` of your gameObject, or rotating it according to your needs with any of the functions the `Transform` class has for rotation

Comment: Did you manage to understand rotation with 3D vectors?

Comment: I managed to do it, I put the code as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do the thing I wanted. Firstly, I computed a `Vector3` that was orthogonal to the current `transform.forward`; then I rotate that angle around itself of a random angle between 0 and 360 degrees, and finally I used that generated vector as axis for the rotation to apply to the velocity of my object.

Here is the code:

```cs
public static void ChangeObjectDirection(Rigidbody rb, int angle, float velocity)
        {
            // get the transform of rb
            var t = rb.gameObject.transform;

            // get the current velocity direction
            var direction = t.forward;
            // generate a normalized orthogonal vector wrt the current velocity direction
            var orth = OrthogonalVector(direction);

            // rotate the orthogonal vector around himself of a random angle between 0 and 360
            orth = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Random.Range(0, 360), direction) * orth;

            // generate random rotational angle in degrees
            var randomAngle = Random.Range(-angle, angle);

            // rotate the current velocity direction of randomAngle around the orth vector
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(randomAngle, orth) * direction;

            // update the velocity direction
            t.forward = direction;
            rb.velocity = direction * velocity;
        }

private static Vector3 OrthogonalVector(Vector3 u)
        {
            var a = u.x;
            var b = u.y;
            var c = u.z;

            Vector3 v;

            if (b == 0 && c == 0)
            {
                v = new Vector3(0f, 1f, 1f);
            } 
            else if (a == 0 && c == 0)
            {
                v = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 1f);
            } 
            else if (a == 0 && b == 0)
            {
                v = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                if (c != 0)
                {
                    // ax + bx + cz == 0 with x == 1 and y == 1 => z = (-a - b) / c
                    v = new Vector3(1f, 1f, (-a - b) / c);
                }
                else
                {
                    // ax + bx + cz == 0 with y == 1 and z == 1 => c = (-b - c) / a
                    v = new Vector3((-b - c) / a, 1f, 1f);
                }
            }

            v = v.normalized;
            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change directions by a certain angle on a certain axis, making it similar to 2D.

If you are moving the object with its transform you can easily rotate an object with the [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) method on the game object transform.

```cs
//in a script attached to the game object you want to rotate
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Random.Range(90,270), Space.self);
```

You can now use `transform.forward` to move the object.

If you want to go deeper into 3D rotation have a look at [Quaternions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)

> You can use the Quaternion.operator * to rotate one rotation by another, or to rotate a vector by a rotation.

Consider also looking at the [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) class methods such as `Reflect` and `RotateTowards`.

Tip: To keep a consistent speed across all directions, consider normalizing the direction vector, (0,1,1) will travel faster than (0,0,1).

You can normalize any vector as follows:

```cs
Vector3 direction = Vector3.up + Vector3.forward; //(0,1,1)
direction = direction.normalized; //(0,0.71,0.71)
```

Answer (score 0):

> In 2D this is simple...

In three 3 as well.

You can e.g. simply rotate a Vector3 about any given Euler angles via

```
var newVector = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z) * oldVector;
```

question remains where you get those angles from and whether those are random or you are rather looking for [`Reflect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html) the vector once the objects reach your defined area constraints.

You can as well simply invert the individual components like e.g.

```
// Note for simplicity reasons this is not an actual "distance"
// but rather the maximum of each individual axis
public float maxDistance;

private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start ()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    _rigidbody.velocity = Random.insideUnitSphere.normalized;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var vel = _rigidbody.velocity;
    var pos = _rigidbody.position;

    if(Mathf.Abs(pos.x) >= maxDistance)
    {
        vel.x *= -1;
    }

    if(Mathf.Abs(pos.y) >= maxDistance)
    {
        vel.y *= -1;
    }

    if(Mathf.Abs(pos.z) >= maxDistance)
    {
        vel.z *= -1;
    }

    _rigidbody.velocity = vel;
}
```